# Load, Save and Read data in textboxes when ap is opened & closed c# VS 2012

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, xml-serialization

I have an app where the user logins to a list of textboxs where the users can write in them save the data then close the app and when they open it the data is still in the textboxes.

I have been researching .txt and .xml to see which is the best format to use. I have also researched XML Serialization and what code goes in the .xml file but I'm a bit lost with do I have to change the name of the textboxes so that the data loads in the right box? Theres about 15 textboxes on the page itselfs.

I have added using System.Xml.Serialization; to my form.
Also when the user logins in it open an existing form and when the user logouts it just closes the form.

I'm a bit confused on how to load the page with all the data showing, saving the data(Iv created a save button for the textbox page) and also reading the file isn't reading and loading the same?

I'm using visual studio 2012 Winforms c#

Comment: should it be user-specific? If so approach using database may be better. What have you tried? please show some code

Answer (score 4):

You could use the attributes for the XML and name it from the user login.

```
static public void CreateFile(string username)
{
    XmlWriter xmlW = XmlWriter.Create(username + ".xml");
    xmlW.WriteStartDocument();
    xmlW.WriteStartElement("Listofboxs");

//add the box following this canvas
    xmlW.WriteStartElement("box");
    xmlW.WriteAttributeString("nameofbox", "exampleName");
    xmlW.WriteAttributeString("valueofbox", "exampleValue");
    xmlW.WriteEndElement();
   //
    xmlW.WriteEndElement();
    xmlW.WriteEndDocument();
    xmlW.Close();
}
```

this will allow you to create the first file with the username.
Second, to display these informations when reloading your application, here's some code:

```
static public Dictionary<string, string> getBoxValue(string username)
{
     Dictionary<string, string> listofbox = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmldoc.Load(@"./" + username + ".xml");
    XmlNode root = xmldoc.DocumentElement;

    foreach (XmlNode box in root)
    {
 listofbox.Add(box.Attributes[0].Value.ToString(),box.Attributes[1].Value.ToString()); 
    }
return listofbox;
}
```

For each node, the dictionnary will add a pair of string the name of the box and its value.
You can use it to fill your boxes.
I know this code may be a little unefficiency (should use "using" and such) but I hope it could help you.

Answer (score 0):

I can't understanding ur problem completely. show the coding of your program what you want. 
just try when your page is loading clear all textbox data.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = string.Empty;
    }
```

Comment: That doesn't remotely do what the OP is asking for. In the future, please do not post an answer if you don't understand *exactly* what the user is asking.

Answer (score 0):

To read and write the xml-file you can add a dataset to your project, where you define two columns. One column for the name of the textbox and another one for the value. On the dataset you can use the Methods WriteXml and ReadXml to read and write.

To load the xml at startup you have to subscribe for the load-event of the form. And in the Formclosing-event you can write your data.

```
public Form1()
{
   this.Load += OnLoad();
   this.FormClosing += OnFormClosing();
}
private void OnLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // Read Data from Xml with the dataset (dataset.Readxml...)
}
private void OnFormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
   // Write the Data from the textboxes into the xml (dataset.writexml...)
}
```

To set the values of the textboxes in the load-part you can use the following code:

```
TextBox tb = this.Controls.Find("buttonName", true);
if(tb != null)
   // set the value for the tb
```